# SQL - Insertion with specific values and a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, insert

There are two relations (bold keys are attributes):

Apartment(**apartmentId**,address,unit,sqft)

Own(**name**,**apartmentId**)

For the Own relation, I want to insert a tuple with the name 'Bob Smith' and apartmentId corresponding to an address of 100 East Green Street and unit of 204. I know you can do an SQL statement with "INSERT INTO R(A1,...,An) VALUES(V1,..,Vn). But is it possible for me to insert the tuple with the value of 'Bob Smith' and an apartmentId from a subquery?

Comment: yes you can do an `insert` with a sub-query

Comment: I also want to hardcode a value along with using a subquery. How would I do that?

Comment: it is hard to tell unless you show some data and the expected result

Comment: If bob smith is hard coded you can use somthing like inset into tab_name(cols) select 'bob smith', your_cols from your_sub_query. For details read insert into select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can! It is a very basic query so you may want to read your source material a little more and it may provide your answer for you, but it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO R(A1, … An) SELECT A1, … An FROM <table_name_goes_here>
```

You don’t use the VALUES keyword in the syntax when you are inserting the values from a query into a table.

EDIT based on your comment: if you want a hardcoded value, sure! Just add it to your selection, eg:

```
INSERT INTO Own ( Name, ApartmentID ) SELECT 'Bob Smith', ApartmentId FROM <some_table>
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks a lot!